# Python threading.Timer only repeats once

Tags: python, multithreading

```
def On_Instrumentation_StartAnimation():  

    """
    Syntax      : On_Instrumentation_StartAnimation()
    Purpose     : Fired if the animation is started
    Parameters  : None
    """
    print "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    global start
    start = time.clock()
    print "The user entered Animation Mode at local time: ", localtime
    print("This data has also been written to 'c:\dSPACE71\cdlog\cdlog.txt'")   
    threading.Timer(2, ExecuteDemo).start()
    ExecuteDemo()
    # Printing to the text file
    file1 = open('c:\dSPACE71\cdlog\cdlog.txt', 'a')
    file1.write("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    file1.write("\nThe user entered Animation Mode at local time: ")
    file1.write(localtime)
    file1.close()      

def ExecuteDemo()
    .
    .
    .
    Current_value = Current.Read()
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    print "The current reading at localtime:", localtime, "is", str(Current_value) + "."
    # Printing to the text file
    file1 = open('c:\dSPACE71\cdlog\cdlog.txt', 'a')
    file1.write("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    file1.write("\nThe current reading at localtime: ")
    file1.write(localtime)
    file1.write(" is: ")
    file1.write(str(Current_value))
    file1.close()
    .
    .
    .
```

As you can hopefully see, I'm trying to repeat the ExecuteDemo() function every 2 seconds after the StartAnimation function is called. But my problem here is that my ExecuteDemo() only runs twice. How can I get it to keep repeating? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the documentation:

> class threading.Timer
>
> A thread that executes a function after a specified interval has passed.

This means `Threading.Timer` will call a function **after** a specified period of time. And as you noticed, it gets called only once. The solution here will to have the timer set once again at the end of the `ExecuteDemo(..)` function.

```
def ExecuteDemo():
    .
    .
    .
    threading.Timer(2, ExecuteDemo).start()
```

---

In my opinion, the above method is a little inefficient. It is like every 2 seconds a new thread is being created, and once it executes the function, it dies before creating the next thread.

I would suggest something like this:

```
def ExecuteDemoCaller():
    #while True: # or something..
    while someCondition:
        ExecuteDemo()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: +1 for the `while True:` approach.  This is much more Pythonic in my opinion, and much more expressive of the intent, which is to loop indefinitely.  `while breakCondition:` would also be meaningful, assuming that `ExecuteDemo` could change the value stored there.

Comment: @g.d.d.c The reason why I have `# or something` over there :)

Comment: +1 for the same reasons. However, it's worth pointing out that all of the solutions given have the same problem: it won't average out to 30 iterations/minute, it'll always be slower. The only way around that is to use a sleep-until function, with a timestamp that you always increment by 2 seconds.

Comment: PS, a really simple sleep-until function is "delay = t - time.time(); if delay > 0: sleep(delay)". Don't use this for 30fps animation or 20ms audio buffering, but for the OP's use case, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Timer):

> class threading.Timer(*interval*, *function*, *args*=[], *kwargs*={})¶
>   Create a timer that will run *function* with arguments *args* and keyword
>   arguments *kwargs*, after *interval* seconds have passed.

I couldn't find anything about repeatedly calling something. Maybe someone else has a better answer, or maybe you have to do handroll it (which wouldn't be too hard).

Answer (score 1):

```
class setInterval(threading.Thread):
 def __init__(self, interval, function, args=[], kwargs={}):
  threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  self.interval = interval
  self.function = function
  self.args = args
  self.kwargs = kwargs
  self.finished = threading.Event()
  self.flag_run = True
 def cancel(self):
  self.finished.set()
 def run(self):
  while self.flag_run:
   self.finished.wait(self.interval)
   if not self.finished.is_set(): self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
   else: self.flag_run = False
  self.finished.set()
```

After 10 minutes reading of "threading.py" I use this code

Answer (score 0):

Timer doesn't repeat.  You can just set another timer at the end of your callback function.